# Example of LSTMCell usage in MXNet

Tags: python-3.x, mxnet

I'm trying to make use of LSTM Cell, according to this tutorial:
https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.2.1/api/python/gluon/rnn.html

```
model = mx.gluon.rnn.SequentialRNNCell()
model.add(mx.gluon.rnn.LSTMCell(20))
model.add(mx.gluon.rnn.LSTMCell(20))
states = model.begin_state(batch_size=32)
input = mx.nd.random.uniform(shape=(32, 10))
model.initialize()
model(input, states)
```

I'm getting the following error: `ValueError: Deferred initialization failed because shape cannot be inferred. Operator FullyConnected registered in backend is known as FullyConnected in Python. This is a legacy operator which can only accept legacy ndarrays, while received an MXNet numpy ndarray. Please call as_nd_ndarray() upon the numpy ndarray to convert it to a legacy ndarray, and then feed the converted array to this operator.`

What's wrong with it? I'm using MXnet '2.0.0' and can't find any up to date tutorial.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in 2.0.0, it's calling hybrid_forward, which is not implemented for rnn.

Comment: 2.0.0b20201108 version particularly. Worked in 2.0.0b20200720.